# How to declare "string" condition in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a `country` variable which has `"Germany"` values but when I run the regression:

```
oprobit adl iadl depression_scale chronicw2 if country==Germany
```

it said `"Germany not found"`. With

```
oprobit adl iadl depression_scale if "country"=="Germany"
```

it said  `"no observations"`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the variable value in quotes, not its name (so, `oprobit adl iadl depression_scale if country =="Germany"`)

Comment: hence the variable `country` is not a string variable. It might be a numeric variable with value labels. In that case, you should find out the numeric value labeled as "Germany"

Comment: You're welcome. In case you found the answer useful, consider the possibility to mark it as accepted for future references.

Comment: Thank you I find out the numeric value labeled as "Germany" so the code should be `oprobit adl iadl depression_scale if country ==12` where 12 is numeric value of "Germany"